# How to prevent a Chrome App from being closed?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, kiosk-mode

[I am building my first local Chrome App using this tutorial](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/about_apps)

My goal is to build an app that launches fullscreen when the PC is started.
The app can be closed by pressing a certain button (<kbd>Q</kbd>) but otherwise the user should not be able to close the app.

Is this possible using Google Chrome Apps? How do you launch fullscreen, and how do you prevent the user from closing the app?

Can you prevent the user right-clicking to inspect the page, or clicking on the top menu bar to close the app?

Comment: I have found a number of options here: http://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_window but still not a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you may want to [use kiosk mode](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/3134673?hl=en).  Use this [manifest permission for your app](http://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest/kiosk_enabled), [as listed here](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/manifest).

You can enter kiosk mode from the chrome command line as well, with `--kiosk`.

Comment: But I'm not working with a Chromebook... Is Kiosk mode available for Chrome Extensions?

Comment: Good question.  Looks like its ChromeOS only, but I'm not 100%.  Either way, this would be the only way to do this, since the user has to be made very clear that your app will run in this mode.  Otherwise you could trick them and do nasty stuff.  I wouldn't want apps I install to go full screen with no way to quit by default.